# How can i give access to IIS_WPG user role in IIS

Tags: .net, asp.net, iis

How can i give access to IIS_WPG user role in IIS.

I am trying to run .net 2.0 application on windows xp laptop

Answer (score 1):

It's a group on your machine, edit it like this:

- Right click My Computer
- Manage
- Local Users and Groups
- Users
- Double click IUSR_******
- Add whatever user needs it, probably the same account as your Application Pool

Comment: I don't have IIS_WPG under groups

Comment: @WingMan20-10 - Sorry, forgot it was differnt in IIs 5.1/XP, use IUSR_ under Users

Comment: ok thanks that helps.....but i dont understand what you mean by this
"Add whatever user needs it, probably the same account as your Application Pool"

Comment: @WingMan20-10 - Can you clarify a bit what you're trying to do?  XP has IIS 5.1, You're describing a group that was added in IIS6, so what are you trying to assign permissions to do?  There may be a completely different route you need to take for whatever you're trying to do.  For example, if it's file/folder permissions, then you need to go to the file/folder, and assign that IUSER_** to have permissions.

Comment: Well i am getting this error in the event viewer when i try to run my application.

"failed to execute request because the app-domain could not be created"

Comment: @WingMan20-10 - In that case, go to the folder the web app's in, properties, security, and give the IUSR_** read/write access.

Answer (score 0):

Open the microsoft management console and add the local users and groups snapin. There you can find the user group and add your service accounts.

Best Regards,
Oliver Hanappi

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are trying to set permissions on a folder?

Right click the folder and hit the security tab and give permissions to one of a few variations of a user (depends on several factors):
\IUSR_
\ASPNET

Then the user will have access to that folder.