# IIS can't load image from UNC path nor Virtual directory

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7.5

I just mounted a web site locally with IIS manager. I can access the site from the path `http://192.168.154.2/Default.aspx` and I have a folder named Affiche which contains some images and is situated in a remote server from the same network.

To access an image I am using an aspx page GetImage.aspx which work like this:

```
 var path = "//192.168.84.52/Distri/Affiche/10038P.jpg"

    if ((string.IsNullOrEmpty(imageName) == false))
    {

        try
        {
            // Retrieving the image
            System.Drawing.Image fullSizeImg;
            fullSizeImg = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(path);
            // Writing the image directly to the output stream
            fullSizeImg.Save(Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            // Cleaning up the image
            fullSizeImg.Dispose();
        }

        catch (System.IO.FileNotFoundException)
        {
            //MessageBox.Show("There was an error opening the bitmap." +
            //    "Please check the path.");
        }
    }
```

This solution works fine in localhost ( with Visual Studio), I an perfectly get the image with a link like this `http://localhost:3606/GetImage.aspx`, however `http://192.168.154.2/GetImage.aspx` does not work. It will only show a broken image icon.

The remote can be accessed from my computer ( which already input the login) where I have installed the web server.

I tried another solution by using this solution : [a virtual directory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763173%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

From the IIS manager I can perfectly view the files from the remote server, but when I try to access the virtual folder like this: `http://192.168.154.2/afficheImage/20772G.jpg`

I have an 500.19 error with insufficient permissions.

Is there a way to solve this please?

Comment: Give the permission to "IIS_WPG" to your folder which has the images and then try. For more details on same refer [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2344172/how-can-i-give-access-to-iis-wpg-user-role-in-iis)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunatly when I try to add it, it tells that IIS_WPG can't be found. I tried to add it to the local folder where are the site files ( default.aspx,...) and to the folder `Affiche ` from the remote server, but same issue. I did add IIS_IUSRS to the site folder though.

Answer (score 0):

The first line of your code:

```
var path = "//192.168.84.52/Distri/Affiche/10038P.jpg"
```

This is pointing to a different IP address than your website having virtual directory. "192.168.154.2". Are you accessing images from another server? In that case you need to check permissions on another server as well.

Comment: Yes, I am accessing images from another server, the computer where I host the website does have access to the server where there are the images. Do I need to add another permission to the image's server as well ?

Comment: What message do you get when you try to access the image directly? try to access http://192.168.84.52/Distri/Affiche/10038P.jpg from your browser and check if it works.

Comment: I will display a 404 error file can't be found, but if I do like this \\192.168.84.52\Distri\Affiche\10038P.jpg it will work.

Comment: Give the permission to "Everyone" to the image folder and then try.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below line of code for path

> var path = @"\\192.168.84.52\Distri\Affiche\10038P.jpg"

This is correct notation but you gave invalid slashes.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, unfortunatly I can't test it anymore.